# Three women and seven men into two 5-person groups

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Three women and seven men split into two 5-person groups. We wish to form the groups so that each group has at least one woman and at least one man. In how many ways can the groups be formed?

**Update:** Aaron Hendrickson in the comments asks me to show some work. There's $3$ ways the women can be divided, and there's $\binom{7}{4}$ the men can be divided, so there's $3\binom{7}{4} = 105$ ways the groups can be formed. I wonder what others got.

Comment: What is the motivation for this question and where did it come from? What have you tried in solving it? Please include these details in your post to conform it to the MSE quality standards and prevent it from downvots and/or closure.

Comment: Hint: regardless of the distribution there will always be at least one man in each group so that condition is more or less irrelevant. Now ask yourself, in how many ways can you have **no** woman in a group (same as saying all woman went to one group)?

Comment: Are the groups **labeled**, ie does it matter whether a person is in group **A** or group **B** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the groups are not labeled, your answer is correct.  To have at least one man and at least one woman in each group, there must be a group with three men and two women and a group with four men and one woman.  There are three ways to select the woman who is in the group with only one woman and $\binom{7}{4}$ ways to select the four men who are in her group.  Hence, there are $$\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{4} = 105$$ ways to form two groups so that there is at least one man and at least one woman in each group.

**An alternate approach:**

As noted in the comments, since there are seven men, there must be at least one man in each group.  Therefore, the only restriction is that we cannot have a group which contains no women.  This can only occur if all three women are in the same group.

Suppose Amy is one of the three women.  If there were no restrictions, there would be $\binom{9}{4}$ ways to select the other four members of her group.  From these, we must subtract those choices in which the other two women are also in her group.  If the other two women are in Amy's group, two men must also be in Amy's group.  There are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to select the two men who are in the group with all three women.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{9}{4} - \binom{7}{2} = 105$$
ways the two groups of five people can be formed if at least one man and at least one woman is in each group.

Comment: Please explain the reason for the down vote.